# Show specific value of response schema in Swagger UI

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, marshmallow

I'm developing a schema description for methods that can answer with 200 or 40x HTTP codes, and a JSON response with status field. I'd like to make status field be visible with correct values for different responses. I tried two approaches: 1. using `fields.Str` and 2. using `fields.Constant`:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class SchemaSuccess(Schema):
    status = fields.Str(default='SUCCESS', description='Response status')
    status = fields.Constant('SUCCESS')

class SchemaError(Schema):
    status = fields.Str(default='ERROR', description='Response status')
    status = fields.Constant('ERROR')
    description = fields.Str(description='Error description')


from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp_apispec import docs
routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.post('/my_api_method')
@docs(
    summary='Do smth with a phone number',
    description='Do smth with a phone number',
    responses={
        200: {
            'schema': SchemaSuccess,
            'description': 'SMS is sent',
        },
        400: {
            'schema': SchemaError,
            'description': 'Bad request',
        },
    }
)
async def my_api_method(request):
    ...
```

#### 1. `fields.Str`

The value is **not** propagated to the JSON API Spec:

```
{
    "SchemaSuccess": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "status": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Response status"
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Hence no value is shown in the Swagger UI:

[image: fields.Str in the Swagger UI]

#### 2. `fields.Constant`

The value **is** propagated to the JSON API Spec:

```
{
    "SchemaSuccess": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "status": {
                "default": "SUCCESS"
            }
        }
    },
}
```

But the field is not shown at all in the Swagger UI:

[image: fields.Constant in the Swagger UI]

---

So, how can I show specific value of a response schema in the Swagger UI??

<sub>I use Python 3, [`marshmallow`](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow), [`aiohttp-apispec`](https://github.com/maximdanilchenko/aiohttp-apispec), [`apispec`](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/apispec), and [`swagger-ui`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui).</sub>

Comment: Does `fields.Str` has an annotation to add specify the [`example`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-schemaexample) value for this property? Schema examples in Swagger UI use the `example` values if they are provided.

Comment: @Helen Thanks for the reply! I think it's a really good clue. Unfortunately, I don't see anything similar to `example` in the Marshmallow Field class, but [I found the code](https://github.com/maximdanilchenko/aiohttp-apispec/blob/4697941a292b5b3600fd58217a420c5f402b1b05/aiohttp_apispec/aiohttp_apispec.py#L197) in the `aiohttp-apispec` that probably produces example values which are seen on the screenshots. Although I see no interface to affect these value. I'm afraid I have to modify the library...

Comment: @Helen I was wrong, actually the Field class has `example` property which works just like I wanted. So, if you'll write an answer, I will accept it `:)`